# No UPC information in the Spotify Apps API search results?

Tags: metadata, spotify

I'm trying to match the album information retrieved from an external source to the Spotify data. The best way would be to match them by UPC. But unlike [Spotify Metadata API](http://developer.spotify.com/en/metadata-api/search/album/) search results, [Spotify Apps API](http://developer.spotify.com/download/spotify-apps-api/reference/4c26b7e8e0.html) search results don't contain the UPC code information. Is that intentional? Is there any better way of obtaining the UPC code information for a specific album inside the Spotify Apps then using the Metadata API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, unfortunately not - the client doesn't deal with UPC information at all, so it isn't in the client's search results.